# I can't install the rubyracer - I could not create Makefile due to some reason

Tags: ruby, homebrew, therubyracer

```
Installing therubyracer (0.11.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
/Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:50:in `build_with_rubygem_libv8': undefined local variable or method `libv8_include_flags' for main:Object (NameError)
    from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**osx 10.7.5 

rails 3.2.3

ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]**

I would be very grateful if someone could help me figure out why I can't get therubyracer installed.

This is /Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out

```
/Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
/Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:50:in `build_with_rubygem_libv8': undefined local variable or method `libv8_include_flags' for main:Object (NameError)
    from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Comment: how about dumping /Users/jamesharrington/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out for us to see

Comment: it says the same exact thing, ill show you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me in the same error:

```
bundle update therubyracer libv8
```